# Why does decimal library raise comparison errors and fail to return results?

Tags: python

I am writing a math library, mainly for the challenge of it. I received the challenges, all right! I am trying to get the arctan() function working, though to no avail. arctan() uses tan(), which has been tested against a TI 30x IIs calculator and proven to be accurate.

```py
def arccos(ratioin):    #working, sometimes
    if ratioin > 1 or ratioin < -1:
        return False
    else:
        attempt = Decimal('0')
        target = Decimal(str(ratioin))
        for i in range(-2, terms + 1):    #determines the place value for editing
            for j in range(10):    #check 10 times for each place value, possibly excessive, but resource usage isn't currently a concern
                if Decimal(str(cos(float(attempt)))) == target:    #if correct, return.
                    attempt *= -1
                    while attempt > 180:    #limit the range of answers to 180 degrees or less
                        attempt -= 180
                    if attempt == Decimal('-0'):    #eliminate -0 answers
                        attempt = Decimal('0')
                    return attempt

                if Decimal(str(cos(float(attempt)))) < target:    #if too low, increase by the current place value
                    attempt += (Decimal('10') ** -Decimal(str(i)))
                    print(attempt, end = ' ')

                if Decimal(str(cos(float(attempt)))) > target:    #if too high, decrease by the current place value
                    attempt -= (Decimal('10') ** -Decimal(str(i)))


def arctan(ratioin):    #not working
    if ratioin > 1 or ratioin < -1:
        return False
    else:
        attempt = Decimal('0')
        target = Decimal(str(ratioin))
        print(type(target))
        for i in range(-2, terms + 1):
            for j in range(10):
                if Decimal(str(tan(float(attempt)))) == Decimal(target):    #note that in these comparison lines, tan is used, rather than cos
                    return attempt

                if Decimal(str(tan(float(attempt)))) < target:
                    attempt += (Decimal('10') ** -Decimal(str(i)))

                if Decimal(str(tan(float(attempt)))) > target:
                    attempt -= (Decimal('10') ** -Decimal(str(i)))
```

The theory of operation behind arctan() is such:
-Starting with the 100s place, add or subtract 100 to attempt, based on whether tan(attempt) is greater or less than the input.
-repeat the above actions, moving to 10s place, 1s, place, 0.1s, 0.01, down until the number of places specified by terms.

When I call arctan in the terminal, the following error is thrown:

```py
>>>num.arctan(1)
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/ccronk22/Documents/Python_Scripts\numerics.py", line 119, in arctan
    if Decimal(str(tan(float(attempt)))) == Decimal(target):
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
>>>
```

What I don't understand is that my arccos() function uses this same line, except that tan is replaced with cos. Strangely, though, arccos() sometimes works, provided you don't pass 4.9 or 5 in the following:

```py
>>>num.arccos(num.cos(4))
Decimal('4')
>>>num.arccos(num.cos(4.9))
>>>num.arccos(num.cos(5))
>>>
```

Provided you don't give magic numbers, sin(), cos(), arccos(), and tan() are accurate according to my TI 30x IIs calculator. If needed, I can paste the entire library and post it on request.

Comment: Why are you calling it a comparison error? Looking at the error message, it seems to be the conversion to a decimal rather than `==` which is the issue. Thus either`Decimal(str(tan(float(attempt))))` or `Decimal(target)` is the problem.

Comment: The error says conversion is invalid. Usually you give a `str` to your `Decimal()` but in the error specified line, you're giving `target` which is `Decimal(something)`. Shouldn't it be `if Decimal(str(tan(float(attempt)))) == target:`?

Comment: Mr.K I had that originally. Same error. I put target into the decimal block trying to fix this. My testing found that Decimal(Decimal(‘3’)) == Decimal(‘3’).

Comment: This is my custom math lib. I am writing this to challenge myself with python.